# How to install .sh file of timedoctor?

Tags: command-line, sh

I try to install timedoctor time tracker from
https://2.timedoctor.com/activate?authorized=

on my kubuntu 22.04
But I downloaded timedoctor2-setup-3.12.77-linux-x86_64.run file in 129 Mib
and script td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77 .sh with lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

UBUNTU="https://download.timedoctor.com/3.12.77/linux/ubuntu-18.04/interactive/timedoctor2-setup-3.12.77-linux-x86_64.run"

wget -O /tmp/timedoctor-$$.run $UBUNTU

if [ -e /tmp/timedoctor-$$.run ] ; then 
  chmod a+x /tmp/timedoctor-$$.run 
  /tmp/timedoctor-$$.run --nox11 -- ; retval=$?
  rm -fv /tmp/timedoctor-$$.run
  exit $retval
fi
exit 255
```

I tried to run it under Downloads directory, but got errors :

```
master@master-at-home:~/Downloads$ ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh
bash: ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh: Permission denied
master@master-at-home:~/Downloads$ sudo ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh
[sudo] password for master: 
sudo: ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh: command not found
```

How toinstall this package ?

**Failed Attempts :**

I tried to install it twice , as root and non root user, but failed to install :

```
master@master-at-home:~/Downloads$ chmod +x td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh
master@master-at-home:~/Downloads$ sudo ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh
[sudo] password for master: 
--2024-01-05 13:35:29--  https://download.timedoctor.com/3.12.77/linux/ubuntu-18.04/interactive/timedoctor2-setup-3.12.77-linux-x86_64.run
Resolving download.timedoctor.com (download.timedoctor.com)... 34.111.222.85
Connecting to download.timedoctor.com (download.timedoctor.com)|34.111.222.85|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 135458476 (129M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/timedoctor-64396.run’

/tmp/timedoctor-64396.run                            100%[====================================================================================================================>] 129,18M  9,56MB/s    in 13s     

2024-01-05 13:35:43 (9,91 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/timedoctor-64396.run’ saved [135458476/135458476]

Creating directory bitrock-3.12.77
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing bitrock 3.12.77 Package  100%  
ERROR: This script can't be executed as root user, login as regular user and provide root password if required.
removed '/tmp/timedoctor-64396.run'
master@master-at-home:~/Downloads$ ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh
--2024-01-05 13:36:00--  https://download.timedoctor.com/3.12.77/linux/ubuntu-18.04/interactive/timedoctor2-setup-3.12.77-linux-x86_64.run
Resolving download.timedoctor.com (download.timedoctor.com)... 34.111.222.85
Connecting to download.timedoctor.com (download.timedoctor.com)|34.111.222.85|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 135458476 (129M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run’

/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run                            100%[====================================================================================================================>] 129,18M  10,7MB/s    in 13s     

2024-01-05 13:36:13 (10,2 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run’ saved [135458476/135458476]

Creating directory bitrock-3.12.77
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing bitrock 3.12.77 Package/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run: 663: cd: can't cd to bitrock-3.12.77
  100%  
/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run: 678: cd: can't cd to bitrock-3.12.77
SUDO_USER is not set. Running uninstall as master
No TimeDoctor2 instance running!
cp: cannot stat 'bitrock-3.12.77/*': No such file or directory
bash: /home/master/timedoctor2/sys_packagers/install_packages.sh: No such file or directory
find: ‘/home/master/timedoctor2/lib’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./plugins’: No such file or directory
./makeself-setup.sh: line 79: /home/master/timedoctor2/make_symlinks: No such file or directory
removed '/tmp/timedoctor-64787.run'
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Set executee rights on the downloaded .sh file first:  'chmod -x ./td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh'  ?

Comment: @SorenA You probably mean `chmod +x td2-ubuntu-interactive-v3.12.77.sh` ... And I agree as both error messages mostly relate to the script file not being executable.

Comment: Problem seems to be their download and install instructions are only available if you sign up. IMO this is bad practice, since nobody can help you navigate the instructions. Lesson: If you choose to use software where the instructions are not publicly available, you're mostly on your own. However, I believe @Raffa is right about permissions.

Comment: Please read Failed Attempts